How to remove irrelevant information from entity lists?
I want to extract entities using 5 entity lists that I have gathered. The python lists contain around a million elements in each. The lists are Nationality, Organization, Occupation, Religion, Hobby. Problem is, they contain lots of irrelevant data. I need to find a way to filter these lists and only keep relevant entities so I can use them with regex. Suggestions please

What would you define as irrelevant data? Would this for example be incorrectly captured text like for example under hobby you would expect swimming but there is an entry that says swiming or swim or swarm. Would you then delete this line item linked to the entity?
How about using named entity recognition. I find spacey to be very handy.
PERSON:      People, including fictional.
NORP:        Nationalities or religious or political groups.
FAC:         Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.
ORG:         Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.
GPE:         Countries, cities, states.
LOC:         Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water.
PRODUCT:     Objects, vehicles, foods, etc. (Not services.)
EVENT:       Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.
WORK_OF_ART: Titles of books, songs, etc.
LAW:         Named documents made into laws.
LANGUAGE:    Any named language.
DATE:        Absolute or relative dates or periods.
TIME:        Times smaller than a day.
PERCENT:     Percentage, including ”%“.
MONEY:       Monetary values, including unit.
QUANTITY:    Measurements, as of weight or distance.
ORDINAL:     “first”, “second”, etc.
CARDINAL:    Numerals that do not fall under another type.
Some sample code to clean up the organization
import spacy
import pandas as pd
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
file_path = "samplefile.csv"
column_name = "column_name"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
unique_organizations = set()
for text in df[column_name].dropna():
doc = nlp(text)  

for ent in doc.ents:

    if ent.label_ == "ORG":

        unique_organizations.add(ent.text)  

unique_organizations = list(unique_organizations)
print(unique_organizations)
